# Laravel 5.7: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MailableClass' not found

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, controller

I created a Mailable called Class UserRequest
I'm trying to call it from inside a controller buy this is the error I get:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\UserRequest' not found

I also tried `->send(new \UserRequest($msgdata));` but it still doesn't work.

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;


class ContactController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }


    public function sendemail(Request $request)
    {
        $msgdata = array('subject'=>$request->subject,'email'=>$request->email, 'name'=>$request->name,'body'=>$request->body);

        try
        {
            Mail::to('dddddddd@dddsdsf.com')
            ->send(new UserRequest($msgdata));
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the path of your `Mailable` class? Based on error, it is different from `App\Http\Controllers\UserRequest`.

Comment: in the normal mailables folder: "app\Mail\UserRequest.php"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include your class at the top like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\UserRequest; // including your class


class ContactController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }


    public function sendemail(Request $request){

        $msgdata = array('subject'=>$request->subject,'email'=>$request->email, 
        'name'=>$request->name,'body'=>$request->body);

        try {
            Mail::to('dddddddd@dddsdsf.com')->send(new UserRequest($msgdata));
        }catch(Exception $e){
            // Log your exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add 'App\Http\Controllers\UserRequest' to the head

Comment: the class is not a controller it is a mailable, in the Mail directory.

Comment: OP's `Mailable` class path is different from what you have suggested. Please have a look at comments above.

Comment: O it's my fault.

Answer (score 0):

use App\Http\Controllers\UserRequest;

at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the right path to the top as stated by other.

Also check the namespace in the  UserRequest class